# Celery worker service ignoring broker url

Tags: docker-compose, celery

I'm trying to use Celery in my django app with redis as broker.

In my settings file I set `CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://redis:6379'` and `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://redis:6379'` 
And my `docker-compose` file looks like this

```
web: 
    build: 
      context: ./web/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: &web web
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: "gunicorn web.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :4000"
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/web
    expose:
      - "4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - worker
      - beat

db:
    build:
      context: ./database/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - "5432"

redis:
    build:
      context: ./cache/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "6379"

worker:
    build:
      context: ./web/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: *web
    command: "celery -A web worker -l debug"
    ports: []
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

beat:
    build:
      context: ./web/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: *web
    command: "celery -A web beat -l info"
    ports: []
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
```

When I run `docker-compose up` the `beat` service starts well but the `worker`fails with the error

> consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Somehow the `worker` service is trying to use `rabbitmq` as broker

Please someone help shed some lights on what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Any solution so far? I am getting the same problem.

Comment: @TaranjeetSingh I ended up using `rabbitmq` as broker and `redis` as a caching service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed myself.

We need to replace the **CELERY_BROKER_URL** in the settings file as follows

```
# Celery
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://broker/0'
```

Above, the broker refers to the name of the service in docker-compose.yml.

Earlier it was something like this

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

My docker-compose.yml file is as follows

```
#.... other services here 
broker:
    image: redis:alpine
    expose: 
        - "6379"
celery:
    build: ./myapp
    command: celery -A myapp worker -l info
    env_file:
        - .env
    volumes:
        - ./myapp:/opt/myapp
    depends_on:
        - broker
        - db
```